# How to print logs into file and in the cli in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say am running a Spring Boot app via CLI using java command `java -Dserver.port=5743 -jar somejar.jar` and I want the logs to be printed within the cli and also copy into files.

So far I could do only one at a time either on CLI or file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tee utility, it copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files.

`java -Dserver.port=5742 -jar somejar.jar | tee output.file`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) with multiple [appenders](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging) in your application.

Comment: Thanks Tony Stark. It is definitely a helpful tip. But I wanted generic solution that supports other frameworks and languages.

Comment: @kivin6866: You can use Log4j with every other framework (not only Spring Boot) and there are similar implementations in other languages.